# Get SDDL with user SID for local adminsitrator

Tags: c#, .net, security

I am trying to use windows security descriptors to manage the security of some objects that are shared across machines. (the details are not relevant for this question)

I basically build an ACL and convert it into SDDL which I save with the object as its permissions.  I have the system essentially working except that for certain accounts and in particular the local Administrator account, when I call "GetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm()", it is substituting the real SID for an alias.

For example, say I have a local administrator account with the SID

```
S-1-5-21-1234567890-1234567890-1234567890-500
```

i would expect to get sddl like

```
D:(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWP;;;S-1-5-21-1234567890-1234567890-1234567890-500)
```

but instead it comes out as

```
D:(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWP;;;LA)
```

The problem with this is that if the object is shared across different machines, when creating the security object from the sddl string, it will interpret the "LA" as the local administrator on that machine even though it was supposed to be the local administrator on another machine.  The full SID of the local administrator will be machine specific and would not have this problem.  In my case I want to be able to treat the local administrators of different machines as different entities.

Is it possible to get "ObjectSecurity.GetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm" method to output the full sddl instead of the shorter aliased one somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If you make the administrator on the other computer domain administrator in your workgroup D:(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWP;;;DA) should do the trick.

DA is domain administrator in SDDL.

https://itconnect.uw.edu/tools-services-support/it-systems-infrastructure/msinf/other-help/understanding-sddl-syntax/

Otherwise you will have to revert to CO (creator owner) and create with said account on other computers.